# How to stop writing a blank line at the end of csv file - pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

When saving the data to csv, `data.to_csv('csv_data', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', header= False, index = False)`, it creates a blank line at the end of csv file.

How do you avoid that?

It's got to do with the `line_terminator` and it's default value is `n`, for new line.

Is there a way to specify the `line_terminator` to avoid creating a blank line at the end, or do i need to read the csv file, remove the blank line and save it?

Not familiar with pandas.  Your help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: having a line break at the end of the last populated line is pretty standard. why is this a problem?

Comment: the csv file will be used by another script, and can't accept blank lines or extra spaces, the script will break.  I have no access to those scripts. Currently I'm copying the data, pasting it in vim, and removing the last line each time.  I will like to automate it as much as possible.

Comment: If you pass `None` as the file name, pandas returns a string object. `s = data.to_csv(None, sep=',')` for example. You can directly write `s[:-1]` to a file. I am not sure about encoding though. Can you try?

Comment: @ayhan I pass the file name as `None`, returns a string and no longer see the blank line. Is there a way to have this result converted to csv?  If not, I could use the string result with other ways.  I'm such noob in pandas

Comment: @medev21 that result *is* csv. You can simply write it to a file using vanilla Python.

Comment: Yes, juanpa is correct, it is csv. You can write to a file with `open('test.txt', 'w').write(s[:-1])`

Comment: ayhan, juanpa.arrivillaga gotcha! I misunderstood when you said 'write it to a file', but I know what you mean now.  This method works great!  Thanks guys!

Comment: Most answers here ignore the fact that `to_csv` is used by `to_clipboard`. The newline at the end turns into a **bug** because pasting on a spreadsheet actually also pastes a blank line after the data.

Comment: Most all of these suggested comments did not work for me.  None of the answers below worked for me either.  Anyone have suggestions

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to save data except the last entry,with default `line_terminator`(`\n`) and append the last line with `line_terminator=""` .

```
data1 = data.iloc[0:len(data)-1]
data2 = data.iloc[[len(data)-1]]
data1.to_csv('csv_data', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', header= False, index = False)
data2.to_csv('csv_data', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', header= False, index = False,mode='a',line_terminator="")
```

Comment: the last line turned into a series and then each column became a row...

Comment: I tried, it is not working as expected:
`
import pandas as pd
data = {'project': ['france_fec']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.to_csv(index=False, header=False, line_terminator="")
`

Has the library changed over time?

Comment: yes its lineterminator now, no underscore

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the line terminator did not work when I tried it.  (It gave an error, saying line_terminator is an unrecognized keyword argument.)

However, this will do the trick:

```
    df.to_csv(path)
    with open(path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        last = len(lines) - 1
        lines[last] = lines[last].replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
    with open(path, 'w') as wr:
        wr.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: To overcome this error, use this syntax: data.iloc[-1:, 0:-1].to_csv(index=False, sep=',', header=False,mode='a', line_terminator="")

Answer (score 2):

```
file_out = r'c:\your_output_file_path\file_name.csv'
df.to_csv(file_out)
file_data = open(file_out, 'rb').read()
open(file_out, 'wb').write(file_data[:-2])
```

df.to_csv() function has a parameter called line_terminator with a default value of '\n'. This new line character is the issue at hand.

The code above: 
1) writes the dataframe to file as normal 
2) opens the file and reads in the bytes data to the file_data variable 
3) writes the file_data variable back out to the same file but trims off the '\n' with the splice: file_data[:-2]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to not use pandas to export the data to a file. The example below will not include an empty row at the end of the file. However, it's probably a lot slower than pandas' "to_csv" method.

```
import pandas as pd

def export_dataframe_to_file( 
        df: pd.DataFrame, file_name: str, 
        header=True, index=True, delimiter=',',
        line_terminator='\n', encoding='utf-8' 
        ) -> None:
    '''
    This function exports a Pandas DataFrame to a file without
    including an empty row at the very end of the file.
    '''
    number_of_rows, current_row = len(df), 1
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding=encoding) as file :
        if header:
            file.write( 
                delimiter*index + delimiter.join(df.columns) \
                + line_terminator 
                )
        for df_index, series in df.iterrows():
            file.write( 
                (str(df_index) + delimiter)*index \
                + delimiter.join(series.astype( str )) \
                + line_terminator*(not not number_of_rows - current_row)
                )
            current_row += 1
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked because as the original question asked he was trying to send the file to another script/REST API that wouldn't accept carriage return. This is likely caused by the requests library he is using to send the csv file to the REST API.  I was able to use the requests library to send a file which had a carriage return via REST API:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import settings


file_name = Hierarchy.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df.to_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
headers = {
  'x-api-key': settings.MONITOR_REST_API_KEY,
  'x-api-token': settings.MONITOR_REST_API_TOKEN,
  'accept': 'application/json'
}

files = {'file': (file_name, open(file_name, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
monitor_rest_url = "https://api.yourcloud.com"
response = requests.post(monitor_rest_url +'/api/v2/your_endpoint',
                        files=files, verify=False, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```