# vim and wc give different line counts

Tags: python, bash, pandas, wc

I have two csv files that give different results when I use `wc -l` (gives 65 lines for the first, 66 for the second) and when I use `vim file.csv` and then `:$` to go to the bottom of the file (66 lines for both).  I have tried viewing newline characters in `vim` using `:set list` and they look identical.

I have created the second (which shows one extra line with `wc`) was created from the first using `pandas` in Python and `to_csv`.

Is there anything within pandas that might generate new lines or other bash/vim tools I can use to verify the differences?

Comment: Have you tried `diff file.csv file2.csv`. If there is an apparent difference, it should tell you where.

Comment: Thanks.  The rows have been replaced/reordered so there are many differences.  However, when I do a `diff` It does say that there's `No newline at end of file` but I can still sit my cursor on the "line 66".

Comment: That may be a "feature" of your editor. If the contents of your file are equivalent, that is all I would ask for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the last character of the file is not a newline, `wc` won't count the last line:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nc' | wc -l
2
```

In fact, that's how `wc -l` is documented to work: from `man wc`

> ```
>   -l, --lines
>           print the newline counts
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: Many thanks for the response.  I'm still stumped.  The vim line counter clearly states the 66th line.

Comment: It seems pandas is adding a new line at the end of the file.  Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237755/how-to-stop-writing-a-blank-line-at-the-end-of-csv-file-pandas) for those in the future interested in work-arounds.  Thanks all.