# removing rows while converting dataframe into csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I am trying to create a csv from a dataframe based on conditions like if particular column is not null it needs to be added to a csv file. my code does convert the file based on the criteria but in the end It adds an extra null row.[check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYfbF.png)

here is my code:

```
    df= df[pd.notnull(df['TRUCK_ID'])]
    df[['FACILITY', 'TRUCK_ID','LICENSES']].to_csv('E:\Truck.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=',')
```

how can I eliminate the last blank row from the csv file.

Comment: Are you asking about an extra blank line at the end, rather than an actual row containing null values? If so, then check the solutions in [How to stop writing a blank line at the end of csv file - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237755/how-to-stop-writing-a-blank-line-at-the-end-of-csv-file-pandas)

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you for the response and I tried the link you sent over but it is still adding the blank line at the end of file

Comment: I Tried this code and it removed the null line from the bottom but now it is also including the null column to the output file. and I also tried to select particular colums while transferring to csv but it gave me key error.

Comment: fileout = r'E:\Driver.txt'
df1[['FACILITY', 'TRUCK_ID','LICENSES']].to_csv(file_out, header=None, index= None, sep=',')
file_data = open(file_out, 'rb').read()
open(file_out, 'wb').write(file_data[:-2])

Answer (score 0):

You can select every row except the last using `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:-1][['FACILITY', 'TRUCK_ID','LICENSES']].to_csv('E:\Truck.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=',')
```

Comment: I tried that but it is still doing the same thing. is there any other way